# SQL SERVER MIGRATION ASSISTANT for MySql не видит MySql ODBC driver

Tags: mysqli

Делаю миграцию из MySql в MS SQL Server  при помощи SSMA.После нажатия кнопки "Conect to My Sql" появляется диалоговое окно с необходимыми реквизитами, среди которых строка "Driver" в которой  должен появляться список драйверов, но там пусто и напротив этой строки стоит красный кружок с крестиком. Но дело в том, что MySql ODBC  драйвера точно установлены и отображаются в ODBC data source administrator. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана эта проблема?